# How to get value pairs of the objects from JSON using jq

Tags: jq

I have a json file named as param.json that looks as below:

```
[
    {
     "Value": "anshuman.ceg+Dev@gmail.com",
      "Key": "AccountEmail"
    },
    {
      "Value": "DevABC",
      "Key": "AccountName"
    },
    {
      "Value": "Security (ou-nzx5-8ajd1561)",
      "Key": "ManagedOrganizationalUnit"
    },
    {
      "Value": "anshuman.ceg+Dev@gmail.com",
      "Key": "SSOUserEmail"
    },
    {
      "Value": "John",
      "Key": "SSOUserFirstName"
    },
    {
      "Value": "Smith",
      "Key": "SSOUserLastName"
    }
  ]
```

I want to get only the Value for **DevABC** so that I can use while reading the -r line. I need only DevABC

I am using jq as follows which doesn't seem to work

jq -r .[1].Value param.json

Comment: You need quotes around your filter: `jq -r '.[1].Value' param.json`. You may also be interested in using `jq -r 'from_entries.AccountName' param.json`.

Comment: @Anshuman_Mishra - Please be explicit about what distinguishes "DevABC" from the other values.  Is it the value of .Key ? Or is it the position in the array?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all your `Key` values are distinct, you can first convert the array into an object and then access the "AccountName" property directly:

```
jq -r 'from_entries | .AccountName' param.json
```

`from_entries` will generate the following object, which allows you to easily access the value for a given key:

```
{
  "AccountEmail": "anshuman.ceg+Dev@gmail.com",
  "AccountName": "DevABC",
  "ManagedOrganizationalUnit": "Security (ou-nzx5-8ajd1561)",
  "SSOUserEmail": "anshuman.ceg+Dev@gmail.com",
  "SSOUserFirstName": "John",
  "SSOUserLastName": "Smith"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the object keys in the input happen not to be "Key" and "Value" and you can't use `from_entries`, `select` would be a good approach:

```bash
jq --arg k 'AccountName' -r '.[] | select(.Key == $k).Value'
```